# How to get CPU power consumption in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

Is there a way to get CPU power consumption using PS? [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) obviously has a way to return that number, but I wasn't able to find the relevant code in [OHM's source](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched the repo for "temperature" and found this example: https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/blob/da432ef07cf125c019afd3a27f447da428404611/Hardware/LPC/W836XX.cs

It seems to require device-specific classes, such as `OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.LPC.W836XX` for HP and Fujitsu systems or `OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware.LPC.F718XX` for the `F75375` chip used by many graphics cards, for example. These classes know what IO ports and memory addresses that the data is accessible at, **so there is no standard API in Windows (or PowerShell) that all devices put their hardware stats at**: so this situation is very similar to how PC sound-cards were in the early 1990s before DirectSound and OpenAL.

Reading the raw data is accomplished by the code in this file ( https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/blob/da432ef07cf125c019afd3a27f447da428404611/Hardware/Ring0.cs ) which seems to load a hardware driver into the operating system then use IOCtrl (`DeviceIOControl`) to exchange messages with it.

The source code to the driver `WinRing0.sys` is in the same repo, in this location: https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/tree/master/External/WinRing0

As for your actual question: you can get the data you want through PowerShell if you use PowerShell's ability to interact with .NET objects directly - you would just call the OpenHardwareMonitor's class methods directly from within PowerShell, but you would need to run PowerShell with elevated privileges so the OpenHardwareMonitor code can install the `Ring0` driver which enables it to read the per-chip values.

A better idea might be to write a Windows service that exposes this data through some shared pipe which a non-admin PowerShell instance could read from.

For CPU power consumption, that's under `Hardware/CPU` then choose the right class for the CPU in your system. For `IntelCPU` look at use of `MSR_RAPL_POWER_UNIT`.